# LINQ query optimization?

Tags: linq

I have a large unsorted list of items.  Some items are important and need to listed first, followed by unimportant items.  The items should be sorted by name in the two groups.  I have a solution, but I believe it can be optimized.  First, it gets a list of important items.  Then a list of everything else, then concatenates the results.  Any suggestions on how to optimize this?

Here is a simplified version of the problem for LINQPad:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<items>
    <item id='a'>not important4</item>
    <item id='b'>important2</item>
    <item id='c'>not important2</item>
    <item id='d'>not important3</item>
    <item id='e'>important1</item>
    <item id='f'>not important1</item>
</items>");
// identify which items are important
string[] importantItemIDs = new string[] { "b", "e" };
var items = doc.Root.Elements("item");

// get a list of important items (inner join)
var importantList = from itemID in importantItemIDs
            from item in items
            orderby (string) item.Value
            where itemID == (string) item.Attribute("id")
            select item;

// get items that are not important items           
var notImportantList = items.Except(importantList).OrderBy(i => (string) i.Value);

// concatenate both sets of results into one list
var fullList = importantList.Concat(notImportantList);
fullList.Select(v => v.Value).Dump();
```

Here's the correct output:

```
important1
important2
not important1
not important2
not important3
not important4
```

Comment: How do you want it optimized?  For speed of execution?

Comment: Yes, it may be possible to do it in less code, but I'm interested in performance.

Comment: Is it running too slowly now?  Or are you trying to solve a problem that hasn't happened yet?

Comment: It's been implemented and I'm looking for advice on an alternate approach to the problem that may produce better results.  In the real world takes about 1200ms when the item list is in the 25,000 range.  A query on the same data set without the grouping requirement is in the 100ms range.  There's a large gap there and I'm looking for ways to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach that immediately comes to mind is to utilize OrderBy as well as ThenBy to avoid querying the original data source multiple times. Something like:

```
var list = items
       .OrderBy(i => importantItemIDs.Contains(i.Attribute("id") ? 0 : 1)
       .ThenBy(i => i.Value);
       .Select(i => i.Value);
```

I'm not sure if the ternary operator is necessary there - I forget how OrderBy deals with boolean results. Shouldn't be a major performance concern anyway and is potentially a bit clearer.

Comment: Both answers posted so far dramatically improve the original performance and perform similarly well.  This answer gets the nod for being a bit more elegant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prioritized = 
        from item in items 
        select new {
        Importance = importantItemIDs.Contains((string) item.Attribute)? 1 :2,
        Item = item
        };

var fullList =   from pitem in prioritized 
                 orderby pitem.Importance, pitem.Item.Value
                 select pitem.Item.Value;
```